# How to fix : Unexpected keys...found in preloadedState argument passed to createStore.Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have to make an application on the Redux-React. Using the fetch method, I take the API data and output it to the page (list of airplanes departure at the airport). There should also be a search filter, searches for the name of the terminal. And the app should also have buttons for yesterday, today and tomorrow airplane data and their children buttons - departure and arrival.

But in console such error:

> Unexpected keys "day", "data", "filteredData", "search", "shift" found in preloadedState argument passed to createStore. Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead: "propReducer". Unexpected keys will be ignored.

Code:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import App from './components/app';
import reducer from './reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { ConnectedRoot } from './components/app';

const store = createStore(          
  reducer,
  {
    day: 1,
    data: [],
    filteredData: [],
    search: "",
    shift: "departure"
  },
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRoot />
  </Provider> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change your preloaded state to dis way**

```
const store = createStore(
  reducer, 
  {
    propReducer: {
      day: 1,
      data: [],
      filteredData: [],
      search: "",
      shift: "departure"
    }
  }
 ,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

Preloaded state should match with your state object..You cant simply provide keys directly.